# Retry Mechanism Using Axios in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, nestjs

I'm using a 3rd party API to fetch some data and do some stuff in my NestJS application, and sometimes the API throws a 400 Bad Request error, so in that case, I only want to retry my call again after 1 second. So what's the most efficient way of doing this?

`service.ts`

```js
async fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('my-api-irl')
    // .. doing some manipulation with the response
  } catch (error) {
    // I want to retry if the error status is equal to 400
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [library that I've published](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teneff/with-retry) and does exactly that. And in case you want to retry only on `400` error you can implement it like this:

```
import withRetry from "@teneff/with-retry/decorator";
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";

class ErrorOnWhichWeShouldRetry extends Error {
  constructor(readonly cause?: Error) {
    super();
  }
}

export class Something {
  @withRetry({
    errors: [ErrorOnWhichWeShouldRetry],
    maxCalls: 5,
    delay: 1000,
  })
  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("my-api-irl");
      return handleResponse(response);
    } catch (err) {
      if (isAxiosError(err) && err.code === '400') {
        throw new ErrorOnWhichWeShouldRetry(err);
      }
      throw err
    }
  }
}

const isAxiosError = (err: unknown): err is AxiosError => {
  return err instanceof Error && "code" in err;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement to retry an Axios call in your NestJS application when encountering a 400 Bad Request error, you can leverage the [nestjs-axios-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-axios-retry) package that I've developed. This package provides a convenient and efficient way to add retry logic to your HTTP requests. Here's how you can use it in your scenario:

1. Install `nestjs-axios-retry` and `axios-retry` packages:

```
npm install nestjs-axios-retry axios-retry
```

2. Configure `AxiosRetryModule` in your NestJS module - in your `AppModule` (or any other relevant module), import and configure `AxiosRetryModule` as follows:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosRetryModule } from 'nestjs-axios-retry';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AxiosRetryModule.forRoot({
      axiosRetryConfig: {
        retries: 3, // Number of retry attempts
        retryDelay: (retryCount) => 1000, // Fixed 1 second delay between retries
        retryCondition: (error) => error.response.status === 400, // Retry only on 400 Bad Request
      },
    }),
  ],
  // ... Other configurations
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Use `HttpService` in your service - inject `HttpService` provided by NestJS into your service. The retry functionality is now automatically applied based on your module configuration:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.get('your-api-url'),
      );
      // ... do something with the response
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the case where all retries fail
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

async fetchDataWithExponentialBackoff() {
  const response = await firstValueFrom(
    this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
      'axios-retry': {
        retries: 3,
        retryDelay: axiosRetry.exponentialDelay,
      },
    }),
  );
  return response.data;
}

async fetchDataWithOnRetryCallback() {
  const response = await firstValueFrom(
    this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
      'axios-retry': {
        retries: 3,
        onRetry: (retryCount, error, requestConfig) => {
          console.log(`Retrying request attempt ${retryCount}`);
        },
      },
    }),
  );
  return response.data;
}

// Basic fetch data example
  async fetchData() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data'),
    );
    return response.data;
  }

  // Fetch with custom retry configuration
  async fetchDataWithCustomRetry() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
        'axios-retry': {
          retries: 5,
          retryDelay: (retryCount) => retryCount * 1000,
        },
      }),
    );
    return response.data;
  }

  // Fetch with exponential backoff retry
  async fetchDataWithExponentialBackoff() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
        'axios-retry': {
          retries: 3,
          retryDelay: axiosRetry.exponentialDelay,
        },
      }),
    );
    return response.data;
  }

  // Fetch with specific retry condition
  async fetchDataWithRetryCondition() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
        'axios-retry': {
          retries: 3,
          retryCondition: (error) => error?.response?.status === 503,
        },
      }),
    );
    return response.data;
  }

  // Fetch with onRetry callback
  async fetchDataWithOnRetryCallback() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get('https://example.com/data', {
        'axios-retry': {
          retries: 3,
          onRetry: (retryCount, error, requestConfig) => {
            console.log(`Retrying request attempt ${retryCount}`);
          },
        },
      }),
    );
    return response.data;
  }
```

Comment: This does not work at all.